# Mono and C# IOCP: Is it a good idea?

Tags: c#, mono, iocp

I'm porting a c++ app to c# that uses IOCP on it's server.

Can mono handle IOCP as well as windows? will i get comparable performance to c++ or i should try something else?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you target mono for windows? If it is linux then there is a different async i/o model, not completion ports. I assume mono developers did their best to support it.

Answer (score 2):

The main overhead in IOCP is the IO not the language. You **should** expect the same performance from the C# code as in C++ (Given the mature state that Mono is in).

Comment: You should NOT expect the same performance as IOCP must be implemented in the operating system. Linux uses an incompatible pattern of dealing with IO.